# Crashlytics iOS - shutting down after archive

Tags: xcode6, crash-reports, testflight, crashlytics, beta-testing

starting from today my Crashlytics (icon on the system bar) is automatically shutting down after archiving Swift app from Xcode so uploading the app on the server is not possible anymore. I use Crashlytics for almost half a year and just yestardeay everything works fine. I have rebooted the system and Xcode but it didn't help. I use Xcode 6.2.

It seems that there were some update lately in the Crashlytics software so I uninstalled and installed the main Crashlytics.app once again but with no effects.

Asking for help.

Regards,

Michał

Answer (score 0):

I installed Fabric which now integrates Crashlytics and other tools. After reconfiguration of the project (changes in the run script and AppDelegate according to Fabric live plugin) everything works with no problems.

Regards,

Michał